# |G\H| is finite, then either |G| is finite or H = G

Tags: group-theory

Let *G* be a group and *H* a subgroup of *G*. Let |*G\H*| < ∞.
Prove: Either |*G*| < ∞ or *H = G*.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you denote $G\backslash H$ exactly?

Comment: Is $G\setminus H$ the set difference?

Comment: If $H$ is finite then it's clear, and if $H$ is infinite, then so are each of its cosets.

Comment: It is the coset. Sorry, I had to write the question better.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you for your comment. But why is H=G?

Comment: If $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $H = 2 \mathbb{Z}$, how would that work if $G \backslash H$ denotes the set of cosets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints (assuming the question is asking about the set difference and not a quotient):

- If $G$ is finite, then any subset of $G$ is also finite.
- Assume $G$ is infinite and $H$ is a proper subset.  If $H$ is finite, then $G\setminus H$ is infinite.  If $H$ is infinite, then observe that $H$ has at least one coset in $G$ other than $H$, so $G\setminus H$ contains more elements than $H$, so $G\setminus H$ is infinite.
- If $G=H$, then $G\setminus H=\emptyset$, which is finite.

Comment: Sorry, I meant quotient. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: The statement is not true for a quotient.  Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=2\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $|G/H|=2$, but $|G|=\infty$ and $G\not=H$.